# F# This value is not a function

Tags: f#

Playing with F# and it seems that i cannot find out what is wrong.

> FS0003    This value is not a function and cannot be applied. Did you
>   forget to terminate a declaration?
>
> evaporator 25.0 10.0 10.0

```
let evaporator (volumeMl:double) (evapPerDaydouble:double) (threshold:double):int =
    let mutable counter = 0
    let mutable currentVolume = volumeMl
    while (currentVolume > (volumeMl * (threshold / 100.))) do
        currentVolume <- currentVolume - ((currentVolume * threshold / 100.))
        counter <- (counter + 1)
    counter

let result = evaporator 25.0 10.0 10.0

printfn "%f" result
```

**Update**

modified code with `;;`

```
let result = evaporator 25.0 10.0 10.0;;
```

And it is working like expected. Strange.

**Update 2**

[image]

Comment: I just saw the image you added. When I copy your exact code into my IDE I get a different error on a different line. I can't see why you're getting that error. What version of Visual Studio is that? Are there some other unusual whitespace characters that are being stripped out when you copy into Stack Overflow? What if you copy the code back from SO into VS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem with your initial code is that you've used `printfn "%f"` instead of `printfn "%i"`.

If your issue is fixed by adding `;;` it makes me think you are running this in FSI and seeing the compiler error in FSI. This is fine but perhaps you are typing or pasting code directly in to the FSI prompt?

My advice to everyone starting with F#, and even experienced F# users, is to **never** type or paste code into FSI. Write code in your editor, select it, and send it to FSI. This way you don't need to worry about remembering semi-colons, and you get compiler errors and suggestions as you type. I have worked in F# day-to-day for years and never had the need to type directly into FSI.

Also, don't forget to re-run all your function and type definitions in FSI if you change them. It's best to reset FSI and start with clean state if you're seeing confusing errors.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there is leading whitespace. The following example produces this error.

```
        let x = 1
let y = 2
```

Removing the leading whitespace resolves the issue.

```
let x = 1
let y = 2
```

Setting your editor to show whitespace will help detect this.

The reason adding ;; also helps is because it terminates the blocked code created by the leading whitespace.